# Xubuntu: can't exit screensaver, can't login to console

Tags: console, screensaver, xubuntu

I was in the middle of moving my windows partition with `gparted` and the screensaver kicked in. Now, no matter what I press on the keyboard or mouse the screen stays blank. I can get to a console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd>, but when I type in my username and hit enter the cursor just goes to the next line and it doesn't ask for my password (I tried typing it in anyway, with no luck). Can someone tell me how to unblank the GUI or correctly login please? I'd just restart, but I'd lose a day or so of work in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter your username in the console, try to wait a while for the password prompt. It may be that your computer is too busy now, so it can take some time. Note that the login will fail  and it won't work if you type in your password before the prompt.

You could also try to SSH to that box, if you've got `sshd` installed there.

Comment: Once gparted finished it's business the gui popped back up, so problem solved. I'll definitely be installing ssh for next time though.